# A Term for Someone Who Constantly Quotes Film/Literature/Poetry

Tags: terminology

I'm looking for a *"technical"* term for someone who uses quotes from movies, television series, books, poetry, etc. as the basis for conversation and/or to communicate an idea. This person might also give pop quizzes on what movie or book a certain phrase came from.

Is there an actual name for people like this? Any answers would be appreciated.

EDIT:

To clarify, the term I'm looking for doesn't necessarily denote a negative behavior. While this person may use quotes to exercise knowledge or superiority, I was thinking more in the context of someone who enjoyed a book/movie and thought that a certain quote benefited the discussion, often with the knowledge that other people involved were familiar with the reference.

Comment: Could you use _trite_ or _self-absorbed_? The style either creates social awkwardness (I have no original ideas other than what I can quote, my interests must be yours, too, and I am just so cultured) or is the best one can do (Aspbergers).

Comment: @I'd say "citationist," but it's not in common use.

Comment: you can safely add ist to make such words, so it quotes then its quotist

Comment: By no means a technical term (and some may consider it even "loaded"), but what about "nerd"? The stereotypical nerd talks in quotes from shows and books, and if two meet they would have sort of a "reference" battle.'

Comment: Are you searching for a term with a slightly pejorative meaning?

Comment: [**Children of Tama**](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2014/06/star-trek-tng-and-the-limits-of-language-shaka-when-the-walls-fell/372107/). Shaka. When the walls fell.

Comment: I will invent a term: *quote dropper*.

Comment: I'm curious what people think of "postmodernist."  I've heard "postmodern" applied to TV shows with heavy-duty referencing and parody - use of visual or textual material out of context, so effectively quoting - but given the complexity of the term postmodern, a quick search of definitions wasn't able to confirm or deny whether that was a legitimate use.  Then again, calling someone a "postmodernist" for making heavy references might be a bit odd, considering (for example) classical Greek works also made heavy allusions to myth and history.

Comment: "Plato says that the unexamined life is not worth living. But what if the examined life turns out to be a clunker as well?" Kurt Vonnegut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are using direct quotes, they may be a ***quotationist***:

```
A person who habitually uses quotations
```

Despite sounding mildly made-up, the Oxford Living Dictionary notes that it is a term from the field of Literary Criticism first used by Milton in the 17th century.

An ***allusionist*** is [someone who habitually uses *allusion*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/allusionist), which is [an implied or indirect reference](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allusion). So this better describes someone e.g. using or paraphrasing quotes to reference something about their original context rather than someone referencing them by the name of the work.

And of course, given the audial similarity to *illusionist*, it will be less likely to cause confusion when written rather than spoken. Such, I suppose, is the power of the illusionist, to make things appear other than as they are.

Comment: Its a great word, which I'm going to try and use before the end of the week. However... I'd say that quotes are direct references, not indirect of implied ones. if I say something like, 'I don't think much of the outcome of that meeting. Still, tomorrow's another day...' I might be alluding to Gone with the Wind. If I say 'I don't much like the outcome of that meeting. But, as Scarlet would say, 'tomorrow is another day'.' then I'd be quoting from the book. The original question does specify quotes.

Comment: Thank you, @spagirl!  That's a good point.  I'm not sure if a quote is always a direct reference: for instance, if someone asks me if I want them to do something, and I respond, "Make it so," I would say that I am quoting Star Trek in conversation but not directly referencing it.  So if I am right about that, then it would depend on context (and while I don't know about the OP, that's how I would usually use quotes in conversation).  But I did make some changes to reflect your comments.

I did some more digging and came up with "quotationist," which is perhaps more exact.

Answer (score 0):

How about Quoteman ? It would be nice near hundreds words with termination **man**,like statesman,ashman,barman,spokesman,postman.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could call them a “sampler”? 
Like Baby from Baby Driver using quotes from movies and previous statements from others throughout the movie

Answer (score 0):

How about a **Connoisseur**? ...*a person who has a great deal of knowledge about the fine arts, cuisines, or an expert judge in matters of taste.*

The definition doesn't implies that he goes around quoting stuff but *IF* you are a connoisseur then you might quote from time to time to *exercise knowledge or superiority*.

[Connoisseur according to wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connoisseur)